# Date day(24 hours) minus date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I need to take away the day from the date that I get, that is 24 hours minus 23:47:16 I have to get 12:44. I tried to break the date variable into a string and take it away, but I just can’t find the algorithm, maybe this can be done with the moment, tell me please

24:00:00 (minus) (const date or const formattedTime) = ...

(in my example 24:00:00 - 23:47:16 = 12:44)

```
    const date1: any = new Date(Date.now());
    const date2: any = new Date(marked_deletion_at);

    const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);

    const date = new Date(diffTime);
    console.log(date) // Thu Jan 01 1970 23:47:16 GMT+0300
    const hours = date.getHours();
    const minutes = '0' + date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = '0' + date.getSeconds();

    // Will display time in 10:30:23 format
    const formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
    console.log(formattedTime) // 23:47:16
```

Comment: Its unclear what you mean, if you want now (or some other date) -24h, just use the `get*` methods and make a new date `new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours() -24)`.. and so on till the second.

Comment: also by doing `'0' + ` on `minutes` etc its not a date object :/

Comment: I need to get this 24:00:00 (minus) (const date or const formattedTime) = ...

Answer (score 0):

You could do with moment `.diff` method

```js
const datetime = '2020-02-20 23:47:16';
const your_time  = moment(datetime);
const close_time = moment(datetime).endOf('day')
let h = close_time.diff(your_time,'hours')
let m = close_time.diff(your_time,'minutes')

console.log(h+':'+m)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i need to do a subtraction

Comment: which one you want to subtract ?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to subtract a time in h:mm:ss format from 24:00:00, then convert to some common base (e.g. seconds), subtract, then convert back to h:mm:ss, e.g.

```js
// Convert time in h:mm:ss format to seconds
function toSecs(time) {
  let b = time.split(':'); 
  return b[0]*3600 + b[1]*60 + b[2]*1;
}

// Convert seconds to h:mm:ss format
function toTime(secs) {
  return (secs/3600 | 0) + ':' +
    ('' + ((secs%3600)/60 |0)).padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
    ('' + (secs%60)).padStart(2, '0');
}

// Time to midnight tonight
let z = n => (n<10?'0':'') + n;
let now = new Date();
let time = now.getHours() + ':' +
           z(now.getMinutes()) + ':' +
           z(now.getSeconds());
console.log('Current time: ' + time);
console.log('To midnight : ' + toTime(8.64e4 - toSecs(time)))
```

Note that the functions don't handle negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var date1 = moment("2020-03-19 23:47:16");
var date2 = moment("2020-03-19 24:00:00");

var hours = date2.diff(date1, "hours");
var mins = moment
  .utc(moment(date2, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(date1, "HH:mm:ss")))
  .format("mm");
var seconds = moment
  .utc(moment(date2, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(date1, "HH:mm:ss")))
  .format("ss");

console.log(hours);
console.log(mins);
console.log(seconds);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The calculation can be greatly simplified to `let diff = moment.utc(date2.diff(date1));
console.log(diff.format('HH:mm:ss'));`.